# Storing reminders in XML, winforms

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, data-storage

I am developing a reminder application in `winforms`. I am storing the reminders in an `XML` file, so that I don't have to provide any database packages with my app.

The reminders could be repeated as below.

- Never
- Daily
- Weekly
- Monthly
- Yearly

Storing the reminder entry for `Never` OR `Daily` is done as below.

```
<Reminders>
    <Reminder>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <RemindAbout>Anything</RemindAbout>
        <ReminderDate>2014-01-10</ReminderDate>
        <Repeat>Never</Repeat>
        <Intervals>0</Intervals>
        <RepeatDate>0</RepeatDate>
        <RepeatMonth>0</RepeatMonth>
        <RepeatIndefinitely>false</RepeatIndefinitely>
        <AlarmOn>true</AlarmOn>
        <AlarmTime>20:13</AlarmTime>
        <Completed>false</Completed>
    </Reminder>
</Reminders>
```

`Never` will be raised only once when the time comes & will be marked as `Completed = true`.

`Daily` will be raised daily at the specified time & will be updated for the next day, until the user deletes it. It will never be marked as `Completed = true`.

The **problem** is about the other three options : `Weekly`, `Monthly`, `Yearly`.

As the user can choose below options for these three options.

- Interval : integer value (meaning every 3 weeks, every 4 months, every 2 years etc)
- Repeat days (for `Weekly` : e.g., Monday, Thursday)
- Repeat weeks (for `Monthly` : e.g., 1st, 3rd)
- Repeat months (for `Yearly` : e.g., January, June, December)

To make the picture clear, if the user chooses to repeat `Weekly`, `Interval` as 3 and `Repeat Days` as Monday & Thursday, the reminder would be repeated Monday & Thursday of every 3rd week starting from the entry date & time.

The user can choose to repeat the reminder by choosing `Repeat Until` a specified date or can choose to `Repeat Indefinitely`.

My question is how do I go about storing the entries in the `XML`, if the user chooses to `Repeat Indefinitely` OR chooses `Repeat Until` for a longer duration?

I have come up with two possible solutions.

1. Make entries for say next 5-10 years
2. Store the basic entry & check at the application start/day change to make entries for that day only

I think both these solutions are overkill. Is there a better way to accomplish this other than the two above?

**EDIT** : I am using a `Timer` object to check if there is any reminder. This is how I am using it.

```
public partial class frmAddReminder : Form
{
    Timer tTimer = new Timer();    

    private void frmReminder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        //some code here...

        tTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        tTimer.Start();     
    }

    protected void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check if there is any reminder that needs to be shown at this minute
    }
}
```

`Timer` interval is set to 1 minute currently. I am polling if there is any reminder for the minute on every timer tick.

Comment: As far as I understand you have exactly 1 piece of XML which defines all possible occurrences of the event. Why do you now want to duplicate that into many XML pieces?

Comment: @Thomas W. I have added some code for clarification. I am polling every minute to get the reminder for that minute. And I think this can consume time if I check for every reminder every minute, as the reminders can grow in number by the time.